# How can I open HTML page on clicking chrome.notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing Chrome Extension. I want to open HTML page when a user click on notification. notification must appear after certain interval. Everything is working well with set interval and chrome.notification in background.js but **I can't open html page with notification**.Window.open is not working because window is not defined:

```
window.open('PAGE.html');
```

Here's my code
Background.js

```
async function getCurrentTab() {
    let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
    // `tab` will either be a `tabs.Tab` instance or `undefined`.
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
    return tab;
  }
  setInterval(func,60000);
  function func(){
  var opt = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Gympass",
    message: "You have been working for too long on Chrome. Would you like to take a break?",
    iconUrl: "logo.png"
  };
  chrome.notifications.create(opt, creationCallback);
  
  function creationCallback(){
    window.open('PAGE.html');
    //-----------SOME CODE -----------------------
    }
  }
```

Manifest.json

```
{
    "name" : "My Extension",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": { "service_worker": "background.js" },
    "permissions": ["storage",
                    "scripting",
                    "tabs",
                    "alarms",
                    "webNavigation",
                    "notifications",  "activeTab", "contextMenus"],
    "host_permissions": [
                            "http://*/",
                            "https://*/"
                      ],
    "chrome_url_overrides" : {
                        "newtab": "storyboard_break_time.html"
                      },
    "action": {
                    "default_popup": "popup.html"
                },
    "icons": {
                  "16": "/images/logo-16.png",
                  "32": "/images/logo-32.png",
                  "48": "/images/logo-48.png",
                  "128": "/images/logo-128.png"
              }
}
```

I want my extension to generate notification after certain time and then on clicking on that notification  HTML page should open in google chrome.

Comment: Use `chrome.windows.create`, remove creationCallback and use chrome.notifications.onClicked event listener, see the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by using chrome.tabs API
`chrome.tabs.create({ url: "PAGE.html" });`

instead of:
window.open("PAGE.html");

Answer (score 0):

Recreate your `chrome.notification` to rather:

```
var notification = new Notification('Here Comes the Title', {
  icon: 'icon.png',
  body: "Hello World!"
});

notification.onclick = function () {
  window.open("LINK_TO_OPEN");
}
```

Comment: well, it generates an error  " Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Notification': Illegal constructor."

Comment: the major issue I'm getting with my code is I cannot load an HTML page on a chrome browser from my background.js. For background.js Window.open is undefined. Can you please help?

Comment: You need to import `Notification`.

Comment: how can I import it? I was looking for solution but I cannot find it on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Comment: You're developing a Chrome extension, so you should read the documentation at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/